# List unique dates and add line at the beginning of a new month

Tags: google-sheets

I have long (multiple thousand lines and growing) list of data in Sheets which have a date and additional columns with data. Here's a simplified example of this list (=TAB1):

```
Date          Number      Product-ID
02.09.2021    123         1
02.09.2021    2           1
01.09.2021    15          1
01.09.2021    675         2
01.09.2021    45          2
01.09.2021    52          1
31.08.2021    2           1
31.08.2021    78          1
31.08.2021    44          1
31.08.2021    964         2
30.08.2021    1           2
29.08.2021    ...
...
```

Three remarks:

1. The date is formatted to European standard DD.MM.YYYY
2. There definitely is more than one line per day per product (could be a big number depending on the day)
3. (for the formulas below) In the European standard Sheets uses ; instead of , as in `=IF(A;B;C)`

In a different tab (=TAB2), I want to add up all the numbers for a unique date for Product-ID 1. So far I've done it like this:

```
Date                      Sum (if Product-ID=1)
=UNIQUE('TAB1'!A2:A)      =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF('TAB1'!A:A&'TAB1'!C:C;A2:A&"1";'TAB1'!B:B))

02.09.2021                125
01.09.2021                67
31.08.2021                124
30.08.2021                1
29.08.2021                ...
...
```

This works fine so far. Here's what I want to do now:

For every month (here: August and September 2021) I need an additional line above the current date (in this case: above 02.09.2021) AND above a completed month to sum over the whole month for column B. Here's how it should look like:

```
Date                      Sum (if Product-ID=1)
September 2021            192
02.09.2021                125
01.09.2021                67
August 2021               125
31.08.2021                124
30.08.2021                1
29.08.2021                ...
```

Of course, the line for the next day (03.09.2021) should be added above 02.09.2021 and below the sum for the month when it's automatically added to TAB1 on the next day.

I tried to play around with s.th. like `=IF(DAY(UNIQUE('TAB1'!A2:A))=1;...;...)` but didn't get far.

Is there anyone with an idea how to realize s.th. like this?

Comment: I updated my answer, but it would be significantly easier to help if you shared a sample sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You want to learn about QUERY().

in cell A1 of an empty tab.

```
=QUERY('TAB1'!A2:C,"select A,SUM(B) where C = 1 group by A")
```

it makes a very big difference whether your product ids are text or numbers.  the above was written as if they are numbers, but you might have just been simplifying.  If they are text you would write it like this:

```
=QUERY('TAB1'!A2:C,"select A,SUM(B) where C = '1XYZ' group by A")
```

note the single quotes.

if the IDs are a MIX of text and letters then you need to force them all to text values in the *original* data by highlighting the IDs column and choosing Format>Number>Plain Text from the menu bar.

UPDATE:
I understand the requirements better now for intermixing a cumulative month total into the output.  This may work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY({EOMONTH('TAB1'!A2:A,0),'TAB1'!B2:C},"select 'Total',Col1,SUM(Col2) where Col3 = 1 group by 'Total',Col1 label 'Total''',SUM(Col2)''",0);QUERY('TAB1'!A2:C,"select '',A,SUM(B) where C = 1 group by '',A label '''',SUM(B)''",0)},"order by Col2,Col1",0))
```